# chrome extension strange request

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On **every** site I visit this strange chrome-extension request is being sent.
Is there an option to check which extension causes this problem? Can this strange behavior be somehow disabled?

[image: issue]
[image: details]

---

the referef is of course the url I visit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the request shows up in your devtools, the error probably originates from a content script. Often, the extension ID can directly be found in the console tab, because the following will be printed:

> Denying load of chrome-extension://EXTENSIONID/path/to/resource. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

If you don't see such error messages, you can still reduce the number of suspects by looking at the extension IDs listed at `<page context>`, at the bottom of the console in the devtools:

[image: <page context>]
(image source: [Chrome Dev Tools: <page context> and <top frame>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014185/chrome-dev-tools-page-context-and-top-frame))

Disable these extensions one by one (at the extensions page - `chrome://extensions/`), until the error goes away.

After finding the culprit, you can first look in the Chrome Web Store for the extension. E.g.:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/<EXTENSION ID HERE>
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ganlifbpkcplnldliibcbegplfmcfigp
```

With my [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin), you can easily audit the source code. When the ID is not listed on the Chrome Web Store, go to your [user data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory), and look in the `Extensions` directory for a folder with the same name as the found Extension ID.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I have edited my answer to address your previous question, check it out.

Comment: Extension IDs of installed extensions are listed in `chrome://extensions/` when you activate Developer mode