# How do I run script in another frame in Chrome add-on?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So now, I need to write a chrome extension.

From [Chrome Dev Tools: <page context> and <top frame>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014185/chrome-dev-tools-page-context-and-top-frame), I saw a drop down with text "top frame". Good. I know how to use it.

What I want to do is:

> Like for example, there is a frame called "gbsf" in the page. In the frame "gbsf", there is a function called "writeOutput". I want to run this function. How can I do this, or, can I do this?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you already have a content script injected somewhere? What does your extension currently do?

Comment: @Xan I've clarified the question. Is it clear enough to get an answer?

Comment: The script is defined by the page (i.e. it works in that frame)? Is there already a content script from your extension in this frame, or do you need to inject it too?

Comment: @Xan yes, it's defined by the page. That frame already has the function (i.e. imported a piece of script). I need to **use that function**.