# Call Meteor method from client when code is minified

Tags: meteor, methods, minify

In my development environment, I can run `Meteor.call('method.name')` in the browser console to call server methods. However, this doesn't work in production since the code is minified. I get `Meteor is not defined`.

Is there a workaround? I tried `Package.meteor` since the minified code referenced that but it didn't work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a wrong execution context set. Take a look at the difference between two screenshots below. Both taken on the same production app with the code minified.

[image: Console screenshot with no error]
[image: Console screenshot with error]

---

More information about what the execution context is:
[Chrome Dev Tools: <page context> and <top frame>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014185/chrome-dev-tools-page-context-and-top-frame)