# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to click a div whose class name is (xyz)

```js
document.querySelector('.header-search-wrap').click();
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.gammerson.com" frameborder="0" width="500px" height="900px">
 </iframe>
```

so I tried to run run below 
document.querySelector('.xyz').click();
but it gives me

```
error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
```

but when I go to elements windows and search of XYZ class and then again 
go back to console window of chrome and run below code again

```
document.querySelector('.xyz').click();
```

surprisingly it works. I don't know what is the problem can any one help me solve the problem. I tried multiple time it only works when I open source code in elements window and then run the code.

Comment: If there is no such element, the result of `document.querySelector('.xyz')` will be `null` and this will cause that error, since your code actually does `null.click()`. Are you sure you have such element in your page? Can you create a working example? snippet/jsfiddle...

Comment: Can you update your question with HTML markup?

Comment: It sounds like you are loading the script before the page loads. Try putting the script before the closing body tag or put it in the window.onload = function(){/* here */}

Comment: window.onload = function () {document.querySelector('.xyz').click(); }

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ktvvgx4n/

check this jsfiddel

Comment: do the same thing that with this example. When you open the console it will show you Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

but when you search for all .header-search-wrap in elements tab and then again execute 

document.querySelector('.header-search-wrap').click();

it will show you only undefined this means it works.

Comment: The `.header-search-wrap` is not in the same document. It's inside another document (which is the `iframe`).

Comment: so how do it then

Answer (score 1):

You can't select a element by querying the document like `document.querySelector()` **if the element is a child in an `iframe`**; if you want to, you have to retrieve its `document`: [Javascript - Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe)

But the other thing is that you can't access an `iframe` which is not in the same origin (*well, I guess, you haven't specified*) because the **"Same-origin policy" applies**: [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

---

And about your statament:

> When you open the console it will show you Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'click' of null but when you search for all
>   .header-search-wrap in elements tab and then again execute
>   document.querySelector('.header-search-wrap').click(); it will show
>   you only undefined this means it works

This happens because when you inspect an element in said `iframe` the DevTools' "context" ([Chrome Dev Tools: <page context> and <top frame>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014185/chrome-dev-tools-page-context-and-top-frame)) changes to the `iframe`'s and you can use `document.querySelector()` freely.

Comment: so there is no way to do it ?

Comment: @DavidCring if you aren't on the same domain: not really, at least for gammerson.com, other domains could work if they allow Cross-origin via `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply whenever you run

```
document.querySelector('.xyz');
```

And if it says null that means ***at that point of time*** there are no elements with class xyz so calling click() on null results error.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/ktvvgx4n check this jsfiddel 

do the same thing that with this example. When you open the console it will show you Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null but when you search for all .header-search-wrap in elements tab and then again execute document.querySelector('.header-search-wrap').click(); it will show you only undefined this means it works.